# Uniform convergence incorrect proof

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve:

> $f_n(x) = 1 $if$ x=1/n, $
>
> or $0$ otherwise
>
> on the closed segment [0,1]

I am trying to prove that it is not uniformly convergent, however I seem to be able to find a proof for UC. Can somebody tell me where my argument fails.

Fix $\epsilon=1$

By the definition of uniform convergence:

$|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |1/n - 0| = 1/n \le 1/N \le \epsilon$

Therefore f UC on closed segment $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$. We also have that 
$$\sup_{0\le x \le 1} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = |f_n(1/n)-f(1/n)| = 1$$
so $f_n$ can't converge uniformly to $f$.

Your statement $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |1/n-0|$ doesn't make sense. What is your $x$? Also there is no $x$ such that $f_n(x) = 1/n$ (unless $n=x=1$).

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I fix $\epsilon =1$ and $x=1/n$, then n is greater than or equal than N, so n is not less than epsilon. So fails to be uniformly convergent. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: @user127700 No. What do you mean by $n$ is not less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: I have seen my mistake, I must say $|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |1-0| = 1 = \epsilon$ where $\epsilon = 1$ so 1 is not less than $\epsilon$. Is that better?

Comment: That is better (as long as you specify that $x = 1/n$).